# Paralleling via ray issue

Tags: python, ray

```
    @ray.remote
    def parallel1(a):
        Gbr1 = ExponentialSmoothing(endog=series1['Price'],trend = True,damped_trend = True).fit(disp = False)
        pr1 = list(Gbr1.forecast(136).values)[-1]
        return pr1
    @ray.remote
    def parallel2(a):
        Gbr2 = ExponentialSmoothing(endog=series2['Price'],trend = True,damped_trend = True).fit(disp = False)
        pr2 = list(Gbr2.forecast(90).values)[-1]
        return pr2
    x_id = parallel1(-1).remote()
    y_id = parallel2(-1).remote()
    pr1,pr2 = ray.get([x_id,y_id])
```

Tried to parallelize this code but it gives an error: `TypeError: Remote functions cannot be called directly. Instead of running '__main__.parallel1()', try '__main__.parallel1.remote()'`

ray lib was installed via pip

Comment: Well, have you tried running them like `__main__.parallel1.remote()` as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```py
x_id = parallel1.remote(-1)
y_id = parallel2.remote(-1)
```

Comment: do you know how to get num of gpus in ray? Does it work with amd graphic cards?